# Why does magento wait for a request to complete before processing others?

Tags: javascript, ajax, admin-controller

I have added a script to an admin page on a magento site to initiate a long running process and periodically query the progress using `AJAX` (or `XHR`) requests so that it can update a progress bar.

The first request is to the controller function that starts a long running process:

```
var startfeed = new XMLHttpRequest();
startfeed.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        feedComplete(this);
    }
};
startfeed.open("GET", thisFeedUrl, true);
startfeed.send();
```

In the code above, the `thisFeedUrl` variable is the appropriate URL for the following controller action:

```
public function thistakesalongtimeAction()
{
    very_slow_function();
}
```

The `very_slow_function` writes it's current progress to a file, which can be accessed by the following controller action:

```
public function getprogressAction(){
    $progressFileName = getProgressFileName();
    echo file_get_contents($progressFileName);
}
```

This controller is accessed by the following javascript:

```
var feedProgress = new XMLHttpRequest();
feedProgress.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        progress = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        // Update progress bar
        setProgress(progress);
    }
};
feedProgress.open("GET", thisFeedUrl, true);
feedProgress.send();
```

The problem is that the requests for progress do not complete until the long running action has completed. How can I get the progress bar to update correctly while the long running process is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX requests for the progress reports are probably being forced to wait for the first request because they are running in the same PHP session. The request that takes a long time to complete acquires the session lock and holds it until `thistakesalongtimeAction()` has returned. That means that the other action will wait for the lock to be released.

You can force the lock to release early by closing the session with [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php):

```
public function thistakesalongtimeAction()
{
    session_write_close();
    very_slow_function();
}
```

You should also be careful that you don't start too many long running requests. If you have lots of slow actions that you run concurrently, you might [hit the browser's limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) for the number of concurrent requests and then you won't be able to make the progress-report requests.

Comment: Note: Don't forget that this will only work if `very_slow_function()` doesn't need the session to remain open. If it does need to read or modify the session, this will not work.